# How do I write a cron which run only on any hour and half (xx:30)

Tags: linux, cron

How to write a cron which run only on any hour and half (xx:30) ?
For example it would run only at 00:30, 01:30, 02:30, on so on until 23:30.

Comment: People would usually call that "every hour on the half-hour".  Your phrasing makes it sound like you want it to run every 90 minutes, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I mean, "every hour on the half-hour". My english is not very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first field in a crontab entry is the minutes.  You want your job to run whenever the "minutes" part of the current time equals 30, so you need a 30 in the first field.  You want it to run at such a time regardless of what the hours, days, or months are, so you put `*` in the remaining fields.

```
30 * * * * /my/job
```

Comment: Thank you very much!